# For which constant is there a unique solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations

For the stated boundary value problem there is a constant k which determines if there is a unique solution for arbitrary f(x).
I think it should be solvable via eigenfunction expansion. First making the bounary conditions homogeneus and then pluggin in sines as the eigenfunctions.

However i dont see how the factor k plays into this. Is it as simple as k has to be n*pi/L such that the sines are 0 at u(L)?

[The question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7JBT.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I edited my question